# How to get all characters between html tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to get everything between div tags on our forum to process them in a program, fetched page comes like this :

```
<div id="post_message_1234567">

        <a href="http://blahblah.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://blahblah.com/iuhiuhuh.gif" border="0" alt="" /></a> <br />
<br />
jofjhoeifjoiwefjoweifj<br />
 blahblahblahpokpoekpfowef<br />
<br />
khfiudhfisduhfiusdfh<br />
<br />
<a href="http://blah.com/img.php?image=trepazoid.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://blah.com/loc367/euhfwieufhwifuhiwefuh.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a><br />
<br />
one<br />
 two*three<br />
 87879879 nuts<br />
 11 bananas<br />
<br />
<a href="hjoiwjhfoweif.dat" target="_blank">Monkeys</a>
        </div>
```

I tried with this regex code but it didn't help :

```
string find = "\\b<div id=\"post_message_\\d+\">\\n*.*</div>\\b";
```

Can you please help me to get everything between `<div id="post_message_1234567">` and `</div>`?

Comment: Add tildas around your HTML tags in your non-code blocks of text on the post. They don't show up in your post without them,.

Comment: You can make use of the HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion lordkain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
@"<div id=""post_message_\d+"">(?<Content>(\r|\n|.)*)</div>"
```

Example:

```
string searchString = @"<div id=""post_message_1234567"">

        <a href=""http://blahblah.com"" target=""_blank""><img src=""http://blahblah.com/iuhiuhuh.gif"" border=""0"" alt="""" /></a> <br />
<br />
jofjhoeifjoiwefjoweifj<br />
 blahblahblahpokpoekpfowef<br />
<br />
khfiudhfisduhfiusdfh<br />
<br />
<a href=""http://blah.com/img.php?image=trepazoid.jpg"" target=""_blank""><img src=""http://blah.com/loc367/euhfwieufhwifuhiwefuh.jpg"" border=""0"" alt="""" /></a><br />
<br />
one<br />
 two*three<br />
 87879879 nuts<br />
 11 bananas<br />
<br />
<a href=""hjoiwjhfoweif.dat"" target=""_blank"">Monkeys</a>
        </div>";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<div id=""post_message_\d+"">(?<Content>(\r|\n|.)*)</div>");
Match match = regex.Match(searchString);
bool success = match.Success; // True
string content = match.Groups["Content"].Value;
```

`content` now contains everything between the tags you want.

Comment: many thanks Ben it worked like a charm. I would like to ask one more question since some pages have many posts between <div> tags as I mentioned above how can I get them separately ? because this code gets the last </div> as end point

Comment: It'd be hard to tell without seeing more of the source of the page.  I've used regex to parse html before, when it was the easiest solution, but it sounds like you may want to consider the HtmlAgilityPack (as mentioned in the comments on your question).  Personally, I really like ScrapySharp (an extension to the HtmlAgilityPack) when things move beyond a simple regex.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407681/best-way-to-scrape-source-code-from-a-webpage/18407718#18407718